# Transverse wave oscillations

Tags: waves

When a wave particle oscillates, the kinetic energy at extreme positions is zero while at mean positions it's maximum... shouldn't it be the other way round as at extreme positions the velocity is the greatest?

Comment: What do you mean by a "wave particle" and why is this a problem if you use the SHO model?

Comment: The velocity is usually 0 at the extreme positions. This can be visualized easily, since the direction in which the body travels is changing.

Comment: ohhh alright... what about kinetic energy at extremes?

Comment: Kinetic energy at the extremes is also zero, because the velocity is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the particle is moving with simple harmonic motion then the relationship between velocity $v$, displacement $x$ and amplitude $A$ is.

$v^2= \omega^2(A^2-x^2)$ where $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{\text{period}}$

Note that the velocity is a maximum when the displacement is zero.

This equation comes from  the use of the conservation of energy where at all times the total energy of the system $(\frac 12 m \omega^2 A^2$) is equal to the potential energy $(\frac 12 m \omega^2 x^2$) plus the kinetic energy $(\frac 12 m v^2)$ where $m$ is the mass of the particle.

Answer (score 0):

In a mathematical perspective, Kinetic energy is defined as

KE = ( 1 / 2 ) × m × v^2.

And your particle's motion plotted over time is defined as

f( t ) = sin( t ).

---

To calculate your particle's velocity at any given moment, we have to get its rate of change. With calculus, this is done by taking the function's derivative in respect to *t*.

v( t ) = d/dt sin( t ) = cos( t )

Basically, we are calculating the slope of the tangent line for every point on the function **f( t )**. The slope is the particle's velocity at that given moment.

---

Now the extremes of the function **f( t )** is located at pi/2, 3pi/2, 5pi/2, etc.. And since trigonometric functions are periodic, we can evaluate at one extreme and it will be the same for all extremes. Therefore,

v( pi/2 ) = cos( pi/2 ) = 0

And if we attempt to find the kinetic energy of the particle at that point, it will be

KE = ( 1 / 2 ) × m × 0^2 = 0

---

Now the mean points of the function **f( t )** is located at pi, 2pi, 3pi, etc.. And since trigonometric functions are periodic, we can evaluate at one mean point and it will be the same for all mean points. Therefore,

v( pi ) = cos( pi ) = 1

And if we attempt to find the kinetic energy of the particle at that point, it will be

KE = ( 1 / 2 ) × m × 1^2 = m / 2

Also, since the maximum squared value of a cosine function is **1**, the maximum kinetic energy of the particle is at the mean points.